# Set state with axios config event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, axios

How do I add Axios event result to the state?

1. Upload file with axios post method
2. Set state into config `onUploadProgress` event of axios post metod
3. Receive the following error

[image]

This is my code:

```
export default class StudioAlbumUpload extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = { prog: 0 };
    }

    onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles){
        var files = acceptedFiles;
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', files[0]);

        var config = {
            onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
                var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
                //How set state with percentCompleted?
                this.setState({prog: percentCompleted}); 
            }
        };

        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/studio/album/upload`, data, config)
            .then((response) => console.log('hello'))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.prog}
                <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} maxSize={5120} accept={'image/*'}>
                    <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
                </Dropzone>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to bind the context of 'this' to the function so you are able to use setState. What is the actual error you seeing? Is there a console error?

Comment: @ahmet what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Fix code formatting and make some sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Arrow Function**

Your `onUploadProgress` function has its own `this` **context**. But you need to use the components `this.setState` method. So you are better of using an `=>` **arrow function**, which does not have a context bound and uses the previous `this` context.

```
var config = {
    onUploadProgress:(progressEvent) => {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
        this.setState({prog: percentCompleted}); //How set state with percentCompleted?
    }
};
```

learn more about arrow functions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

**Change function context**

Learn more about binding here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method

```
var config = {
    onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
        this.setState({prog: percentCompleted}); //How set state with percentCompleted?
    }.bind(this)
};
```